# Quickest way to include graphics

Tags: graphics

Whenever I make a presentation with LaTeX, it takes me a long time to include the graphics in the way I want them to look.

- I start with `\includegraphics{foo.jpg}`,
- run `pdflatex` to see what it looks like,
- then add `[trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm]`,
- run `pdflatex` to see what it looks like,
- then add `[scale=.8]`,
- then run `pdflatex`,
- then change `[trim=...]`,
- then change `[scale]....` etc.

Is there a tool that lets on manipulate the picture directly and then produces the LaTeX source? Or what is a better practice to achieve the results?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A good practice IMHO is, depending on the type of graphic:

- **Photos**: Use the JPG format and crop it to the size and viewport your need using an image processing program, e.g. Gimp or Photoshop. DO NOT use JPG for anything else, it is really just thought for photos. It can handle other stuff as well but not as good as other formats.
- **Screenshoots** and other **Artificial Pixel-graphics**: Use PNG format and again crop it to the size and viewport needed. The PNG format is lossless, i.e. doesn't create artifacts like JPG. Its compresses this kind of images well.
- **Diagrams, Pictures** and other **Vector-graphics**: Should really be included as vector-graphics and not as pixel-graphics (and if so NOT as JPG!). You should export them as PDF or EPS which is then converted to PDF (e.g. `epstopdf`). Extra whitespace from margins etc. can be removed by `pdfcrop`.

To include your image:

- the `width` (and `height`) option should IMHO be preferred before `scale` in many cases, e.g. larger graphics. A `width=`*x*`\textwidth` (*x* = 0.95 .. 0.8) normally includes larger images nicely. The `scale` options is better suited to increase smaller images or adjust middle sized images when they already have almost the correct size.
- In `beamer` presentation I had to watch the `height` as well. Note that in `beamer` the `\textheight` spans over the frame title, so `height=\textheight` will not result in a good slide.

About your current method:

- If you are using `trim` to remove white space (see also above), you might want to also use the `clip` option to get fully rid of it. (Ok, with white space it doesn't make much difference)
- There are tools which give you a live preview, like the `-pvc` mode of `latexmk`. Use it for the recompilation while you change the settings.
- Note that `beamer` has a `\includeonlyframe` which allows you to only compile certain frame, which speeds things up during adjustments and creation of e.g. TikZ pictures.

Answer (score 21):

use package `overpic` for an overlay grid. Then it is easy to find
the correct values for trim:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\begin{document}

\begin{overpic}[scale=.25,grid,tics=10]{tiger}
\end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I run this example with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`, because there is only a `tiger.eps`.  Use any other `jpg`, `png` or `pdf` graphic, if you want to run `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3):

I would create the graphic at the size I want in the paper (for example, by using a graphics editing program) and then use `\includegraphics{foo}` with no other modifications needed.

Comment: But be careful to use the correct DPI value (72, 300?) for it, otherwise it will be in a different size once in the PDF.

Comment: @Martin: As I understand, the image doesn't need to have the "correct" resolution, as long as it has the information about its resolution in its metadata. If it doesn't, LaTeX will assume a default resolution (which is what happened in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10397/2552)).

Comment: @Jake: This is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "fine-tuning" bit of your question (of how to best integrate pictures into your document) you may also find using an editor like [`gummi`](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi) useful, which offers **live previews** while editing.