# Scalebox - knowing how much it scales

Tags: graphics, scaling

I am relatively new to LaTeX and I was playing around with figures and came across the scalebox command. This apparently lets you scale a graph that you create or import into your LaTeX document by a certain amount. How do you know how much scalebox will scale your figure by? I read somewhere that typing `\scalebox{0.5}` scales a graph to 0.8 times the original size. Is there any way to figure out what fraction of the original size your graph will become?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to begin your questions with a greeting.

Comment: but does 1 = 2?

Comment: which package you need to input "\scalebox" ?

Comment: @wonderich it looks like `adjustbox`, but that lists dependencies and it is not clear exactly which are automatically loaded, and which are not.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It is not true that `\scalebox{0.5}` of the `graphics` package scales a graph to 0.8 times of the original size. It scales it simply by this factor, as Ian Thompson already said in his answer.

Note that their is also `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<content>}` which allows you to scale the image to a given size. This can be more useful for adjusting bigger graphics or pictures: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{<content>}` scales the content directly to the size of the main text. The `!` for the height states that it should scale with the width.
See my answer to [Quickest way to include graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/quickest-way-to-include-graphics/10970#10970) for more explanation about scale vs. direct width/height.

See the [`graphics/x`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics) manual for the other commands like `\rotatebox`.
Note that if you want to resize images you can use the optional arguments of `\includegraphics[height=<height>,width=<width>,angle=<angle>,keepaspectratio]{<filename>}`.

For other things like diagrams drawn using TeX commands ([`pgf`/`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), [`pstricks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks), etc.) there is the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package which gives you `\adjustbox{height=<height>,width=<width>,angle=<angle>,keepaspectratio}{<TeX content>}` or the similar and very new [`gincltex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gincltex) which allows you to include `.tex` files like images using `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 54):

`\scalebox{0.5}{stuff}`

scales `stuff` by 1/2 in the horizontal direction, and 1/2 in the vertical direction, so the result will be 1/4 the original size. A vertical scaling that is different from the horizontal scaling can be specified with an optional argument, e.g.

`\scalebox{0.5}[0.25]{stuff}`.

Applying this command will scale horizontally by 0.5 and vertically by 0.25.