# In directed graph how to place a letter over a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[Query link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284407/how-can-i-draw-a-tree-structure-graph/284412?noredirect=1#comment686274_284412)

In directed graph how to place a letter over top MWE T1 to place letter p1.
i tried but the letter goes far and i need without disturbing any other node to place it and how to omit the link numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,initial/.style={}]
    \node[state] (T1) {$T1$};
    \node[state] (T4) [below =of T1] {$T4$};
    \node[state] (T3) [left  =of T4] {$T3$};
    \node[state] (T2) [left  =of T3] {$T2$};
    \node[state] (T5) [right =of T4] {$T5$};
    \node[state] (T6) [right =of T5] {$T6$};
    \node[state] (T8) [below =of T4] {$T8$};
    \node[state] (T7) [left  =of T8] {$T7$};
    \node[state] (T9) [right =of T8] {$T9$};
    \node[state] (T10) [below =of T8] {$T10$};
    \node [above =of T1] {$P1$};
    \node [above =of T2] {$P1$};
    \node [above =of T3] {$P2$};
    \node [above =of T4] {$P3$};
    \node [above =of T5] {$P3$};
    \node [above =of T6] {$P3$};
    \node [above =of T7] {$P2$};
    \node [above =of T8] {$P1$};
    \node [above =of T9] {$P2$};
    \node [above =of T10] {$P2$};
    \tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=black}}
    \tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}}
    \path (T1) edge [mystyle] node {$18$} (T2);
    \path (T1) edge [mystyle] node {$12$} (T3);
    \path (T1) edge [mystyle] node {$9$}  (T4);
    \path (T1) edge [mystyle] node {$11$} (T5);
    \path (T1) edge [mystyle] node {$14$} (T6);
    \path (T2) edge [mystyle] node[pos=0.7] {$19$} (T8);
    \path (T2) edge [mystyle] node {$16$} (T9);
    \path (T3) edge [mystyle] node[pos=0.7] {$23$} (T7);
    \path (T4) edge [mystyle] node {$27$} (T8);
    \path (T4) edge [mystyle] node {$23$} (T9);
    \path (T5) edge [mystyle] node {$13$} (T9);
    \path (T6) edge [mystyle] node {$15$} (T8);
    \path (T7) edge [mystyle] node {$17$} (T10);
    \path (T8) edge [mystyle] node {$11$} (T10);
    \path (T9) edge [mystyle] node {$13$} (T10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want the final output to look like.   And by "link numbers" do you mean the numbers in the arrows or in the nodes themselves?

Comment: Do you mean something like `\node[state,label=above:P1] (T1) {$T1$};`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

[image: connected nodes]

As [Torbjørn T. said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284582/in-directed-graph-how-to-place-a-letter-over-a-node/284629#comment686797_284582) you can use `label` to place nodes labelling the main nodes. You need to vary the positions a bit to avoid conflicts. I'm not sure what the point of `double=black` is. It makes more sense if you also have `draw=white`. I've updated the arrow specifications to use the current library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[color=black]},shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,initial/.style={}]
  \node[state, label=above:$P1$] (T1) {$T1$};
  \node[state, label=95:$P3$] (T4) [below =of T1] {$T4$};
  \node[state, label=above:$P2$] (T3) [left  =of T4] {$T3$};
  \node[state, label=above:$P1$] (T2) [left  =of T3] {$T2$};
  \node[state, label=above:$P3$] (T5) [right =of T4] {$T5$};
  \node[state, label=above:$P3$] (T6) [right =of T5] {$T6$};
  \node[state, label=120:$P1$] (T8) [below =of T4] {$T8$};
  \node[state, label=95:$P2$] (T7) [left  =of T8] {$T7$};
  \node[state, label=85:$P2$] (T9) [right =of T8] {$T9$};
  \node[state, label=95:$P2$] (T10) [below =of T8] {$T10$};
  \begin{scope}[every edge/.append style={->, double=black, draw=white}]
    \path (T1)
      edge   (T2)
      edge   (T3)
      edge   (T4)
      edge   (T5)
      edge   (T6);
    \path (T2)
      edge   (T8)
      edge   (T9);
    \path (T3) edge   (T7);
    \path (T4) edge   (T8);
    \path (T4) edge   (T9);
    \path (T5) edge   (T9);
    \path (T6) edge   (T8);
    \path (T7) edge   (T10);
    \path (T8) edge   (T10);
    \path (T9) edge   (T10);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: when i compile it shows an error `I can't find file tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex`

Comment: Presumably you have an outdated version of PGF/TikZ. You can just switch back to `arrows` and `stealth` rather than `arrows.meta` and `Stealth[]`, although updating your TeX distribution is recommended.