# Small \oplus and \otimes

Tags: symbols, fontsize

I would like to have commands `\smalloplus` and `\smallotimes` that prints same symbols as `oplus` and `otimes` but in a smaller size.

It would look like (but in a more beautiful way and the symbols should be "centered" with respect to the letter) the following

[image]

Is there a classical or convenient way to do it?

Comment: Have your tried using a `scalebox`? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13460/scalebox-knowing-how-much-it-scales (second answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job, *provided* you only want these symbols in text and display style, not in scriptstyle og scriptscriptstyle. If you do, then we'd have to work a bit harder:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\newcommand\smallmath[2]{#1{\raisebox{\dimexpr \fontdimen 22 \textfont 2
      - \fontdimen 22 \scriptscriptfont 2 \relax}{$\scriptscriptstyle #2$}}}
\newcommand\smalloplus{\smallmath\mathbin\oplus}
\newcommand\smallotimes{\smallmath\mathbin\otimes}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$ a \oplus b \otimes c$\\
$ a \smalloplus b \smallotimes c$
\end{document}
```

[image: Comparison of normal and small operators]

Explanation: The `\fontdimen 22` parameters denote the *axis height* of the math font. As we set the symbol in scriptscriptstyle inside a textstyle setting, we need to raise the symbol by the difference of the two axis heights. *Note* that `\dimexpr` requires eTeX; if your LaTeX is not using eTeX, your TeX installation is very old and should be upgraded.

Of course, you may opt for replacing all the `\scriptscript…` by `\script…`, if this is too extreme.

Comment: What about a screenshot comparing both?

Comment: @Sigur As you wish.

Comment: Ow, very nice! And different.

Comment: Thanks  I have replaced by `scriptsize`.

Answer (score 4):

First version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smalloplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\make@small\oplus}}
\newcommand{\smallotimes}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\make@small\otimes}}

\newcommand{\make@small}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    $\m@th\ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else\ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle
     \else\scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi#2$%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\smalloplus b\smallotimes c_{x\smalloplus y\smallotimes z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second version (adjust the scaling factor to suit):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smalloplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\make@small\oplus}}
\newcommand{\smallotimes}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\make@small\otimes}}

\newcommand{\make@small}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \scalebox{0.6}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\smalloplus b\smallotimes c_{x\smalloplus y\smallotimes z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please let me know how to get a smaller \bigstar symbol throughout a document. I was trying to use these codes, but it is not working.

Comment: @ShivaniSengupta If you mean `\bigstar` from `amssymb`, then it's fundamentally different from `\bigoplus` and `\bigotimes`. Please, open a new question explaining your problem and aim.