# Insert WMF file

Tags: graphics

I have a bunch of `.wmf` image files. Is there a way that I can insert those in a LaTeX document without having to convert them to `.eps` files?

I am on Windows.

Comment: Closely related (but not a dupe): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/inserting-a-emf-file-into-a-latex-document

Comment: @JosephWright I had seen that question, but the answers seemed to point to converting the .wmf files to .eps files.

Comment: As I said, I think it's related but not necessarily a dupe. The problem is that the short answer here is 'no'!

Comment: @JosephWright Ok, so I have to convert the files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.wmf` graphics format is not supported directly by any TeX engines. Thus the files will always have to be converted to `.eps` or `.pdf` format. This is discussed in [Inserting a .EMF file into a LaTeX document.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/inserting-a-emf-file-into-a-latex-document) focussing on `.emf` files, but some of the information there also applies to `.wmf` files.