# Inserting EMFs to LaTeX using graphicx

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting a .EMF file into a LaTeX document.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/inserting-a-emf-file-into-a-latex-document)

After years of playing around with different figure formats in R I have found the one to hold its quality best is an EMF. I have just started using LaTeX and cannot get LaTeX to read my EMFs. I am using the `graphicx` package (which I have read here supports EMF files) but its still not reading it.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering
\includegraphics*[width=1\textwidth]{combined_DMC}
\caption{Frequency of fires for each month of the year}
\label{fig_fire_month}
\end{figure}
```

I am not sure if I am telling LaTeX to use the `graphicx` package (as opposed to the standard `graphics` package) by using `\includegraphics*`.

Comment: -1 This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/inserting-a-emf-file-into-a-latex-document and also seems to have been crossposted on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680983/inserting-an-emf-into-latex

Comment: it is horrible to know EMF is the best... I'm wondering how PDF failed you

Comment: @user1189687 May I tell you that both of the reasons you cite are not reasons to downvote? Although I am unaware of the quality of the question, _a priori_, it being a duplicate and/or cross posting are not nice reasons. The OP may be new; but I am only guessing. Or, I am being too generous.

Comment: The votes a post has clues readers into the importance of a post but duplicates and cross-posts should not exist so unless they have negative votes the system is corrupted and all readers are inconvenienced by needless being drawn to such posts more than they really wished to. The fact that the OP may be new is not a valid reason to corrupt the system.

Comment: @user1189687 --- If it's a duplicate it will be closed. There is no need for a downvote and (as far as I can see) no 'corruption' of the system.