# Image from \includegraphics showing in wrong image size

Tags: graphics, dimensions, resolution

When I use the following to embed an image:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics{my_image} 
\caption{blaaa} 
\label{fig:blaaa}           
\end{figure}
```

whereas `my_image` is a JPG file, the image doesn't show in the correct format. It gets displayed bigger than the original `my_image.jpg` itself is and thus the quality is quite bad. Even when I do

```
\includegraphics[width=300px,height=100px]{my_image}
```

for a picture `my_image.jpg` which is exactly 300px*100px in size, it gets displayed in greater size and stretched :( I have no header declaration which change `\includegraphics` settings.
I would like images with plain `\includegraphics{my_image}` to be displayed in their REAL size.

Comment: Your picture probably doesn't have the correct (or any) resolution information set, which is why it will appear scaled. See the answer to [How to Include Picture in Original Size Into Document Page on Centre](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10397/how-to-include-picture-in-original-size-into-document-page-on-center/10399#10399) for one way of fixing this.

Comment: Seems to me that @Jake is right. Try to fix the image file by loading and re-saving it with a graphic tool. Under Linux you could try `convert orig_image.jpg new_image.jpg`.

Comment: @Martin: Just running `convert` will preserve the resolution and unit information. If you want to change them, you will have to explicitly specify them using `convert <original file> density <resolution> -units PixelsPerCentimeter <new file>`.

Comment: It shouldn't be forgotten that `px` dimensions in pdftex have little to do with the resolution of included images. The default value of 1px is given by 72px = 1in.

Comment: But how than can a program like irfanview know the dimensions of the picture? But thanks I'll try it out! Edit: But when specifying the correct dimensions by using `\includegraphics[width=300px,height=100px]{my_image}` why doesn't it work than correctly?

Comment: @Marc: IrfanView just displays the image at the natural resolution of the computer screen, so one image pixel is one screen pixel. LaTeX can't do that, because there is no equivalent concept of a natural resolution in a print document; instead it assumes the image to have a resolution of 72 pixels per inch if no other resolution information is provided in the metadata of the image (just providing `width=300px,height=100px` does not provide resolution information).

Comment: Okay thanks, I opened it in irfan view and resaved it, but this doesn't work. But I think I understand now: Resolution is NOT the width/height of an image, but it's the pixels/inch setting!? I don't see any way in irfan view to save that information to the picture... Edit: Is there any option in includegraphics to set the resolution to 72DPI!?

Comment: Edit: (can't edit the above comment anymore): I tried it with a pdf-image now: But when embedding it the image doesn't appear the same size as the image when setting the pdf viewer displaying the pdf-image to 100%... omg :( Sorry, but I really don't get all this stuff!

Comment: In IrfanView 4.30, you can click `Image - Information` (or press `I`) to show the metadata of the image. The fifth row is called `Resolution` and should contain two fields in which you can set the horizontal and vertical resolution in dots per inch. By pressing the button `Change`, the new resolution will be set. The "physical" size of the image in cm and inch, which is obtained by multiplying the size in pixels with the resolution, is shown in the eigth line, called "Print Size (from DPI)".

Comment: @Marc: On a side note, you can notify people of comments you write; see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n/599#599

Comment: @MarcEdlo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/635/discussion-between-jake-and-marc-edlo)

Comment: We figured it out, so when you are interested, read the chatlog!

Comment: @Jake: Should this still be closed as a duplicate, or does the question need a new answer (I don't want to read the chatlog :) )

Comment: @Caramdir: I totally understand =) I'll write a summary of the chat later tonight, we did cover some ground that wasn't part of the linked question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you take a screenshot or export a figure from Matlab as a rasterised image,usually the resulting image file will not contain any resolution information (or "pixel density", usually measured in "dots per inch", or "DPI")  in its metadata. When you include such an image in a LaTeX document using `\includegraphics`, a resolution of 72 DPI will be assumed. For example, that means that a screenshot that has a size of 1440x900 px will have a width of 1440 px / 72 px per in = 20 in = 51 cm in your PDF or DVI, so it will most likely be too big for your document. A computer monitor with a horizontal width of 15 in (= 38 cm) that is operated at a screen size of 1440x900 px has a resolution of 1440 px / 15 in = 96 dpi. If you want your screenshot to have the same size (in this case a width of 38 cm) both on your computer screen and in the printed document, you need find a way of letting LaTeX know that the resolution of the image is 96 DPI. There are a number of ways you can do this:

**As an option to `includegraphics`:**
If you're compiling your document using `pdflatex`, you can specify the resolution of the image by loading it using `\includegraphics [resolution=<resolution in DPI>] {<filename>}`. This will only work if no resolution information is included in the image.

**By setting the image metadata using GIMP:**
Go to `Image` -> `Scale Image...` and adjust the X and Y resolution after making sure `pixels/in` is chosen in the drop down menu. Then save your image.

**By setting the image metadata using IrfanView:**
In IrfanView 4.30, you can click `Image - Information` (or press <kbd>I</kbd>) to show the metadata of the image. The fifth row is called `Resolution` and should contain two fields in which you can set the horizontal and vertical resolution in dots per inch. By pressing the button `Change`, the new resolution will be set. The "physical" size of the image in cm and inch, which is obtained by multiplying the size in pixels with the resolution, is shown in the eigth line, called `Print Size (from DPI)`. You can then include the image in your LaTeX document by calling `\includegraphics {<filename>}` without any extra options.

**By setting the image metadata using ImageMagick:**
On Linux systems, frequently the ImageMagick programs are already present or can easily be installed. You can then set the resolution information by calling `convert <original file name> -density <resolution> -units PixelsPerInch <new file name>` in a shell. You can then include the image in your LaTeX document by calling `\includegraphics {<filename>}` without any extra options.

Comment: Also using [Phil Harvey's ExifTool (here in GNU/Linux)](http://search.cpan.org/~exiftool/Image-ExifTool-9.76/exiftool): `exiftool -xresolution=72 -yresolution=72 some.jpg`. Check it with `exiftool some.jpg|egrep ' Resolution'`.

Comment: @cyberSingularity are you using pdflatex? In my case, `[resolution=..]` also has no apparent effect. I'm using the sublime text plugin latexing which uses latexmk which (I think) users pdflatex (and the output is a pdf..).

Comment: It is defined in pdftex.def: %% * Option "resolution" (graphicx/experimental): this sets
%%   \pdfimageresolution, see pdfTeX documentation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Jake: Aha, thank you. I had missed that as it is not in the `graphics` folder. I will delete all my incorrect comments now... I have retested and it does indeed work for me. Perhaps I had included the same image with multiple different resolutions when I originally tested, which does not work.