# XeLaTeX and graphicx don't seem to work well

Tags: graphics, xetex

I am having trouble getting the `graphicx` package to work well when running XeLaTeX on my MAC.  I am including `.jpg` files; some of them scale very nicely, but others don't.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{behistun_photo.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{behistun_photo.jpg} 
\includegraphics[width=1in]{graphics/Ishango_IRSNB.jpg} 
\includegraphics[width=2in]{graphics/Ishango_IRSNB.jpg} 
\end{document}
```

When I compile using PDFLaTeX, it works just fine.  The images are scaled properly.  When I compile using XeLaTeX, the first `jpg` file scales properly, but not the second.  In addition, the image in the second one over-writes the lines above.  It seems that it is setting the correct space for the scaled picture, but then inserting a much larger one.

Comment: It is quite hard to diagnose the problem without the actual images. Have you made sure the images don't have something fishy going on? Also, can you go into a bit more detail on how the images are scaled improperly?

Comment: Is your tex distribution up to date?

Comment: All the function for scaling graphics is in `xetex.def` - there were several changes for TexLive2014.  Since you are on a mac, you might find it more reliable to use Preview to convert your images to PDF first.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Image from \includegraphics showing in wrong image size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21627/42880) and [How to force pdfTeX and XeTeX to produce the same measurement for the imported image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24834/42880). You need to use an external tool to set the resolution metadata for the images that aren't displaying correctly (see the comments and answers on those questions for more details).