# Which package is using \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, packages

Which package is using `\includegraphics`?

I have a issue in my installation package, I need to know which package is using `\includegraphics`.

The issue is picture showing like a DOT . If we zoom (6400%) that place the picture can see some what TeX image in top.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfigure[random caption 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{pic1.jpg}}\quad
  \subfigure[random caption 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{pic2.jpg}}
\end{figure*}

Text
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10\textwidth]{pic1.jpg}
    \caption{IDEF0sss}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=30mm, height=20mm]{pic1.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code in there. It's not a good idea to put everything into a comment. It would be a great thing to know what exactly you want to achieve. To find all packages _using_ `\includegraphics` it would be sufficient to make a search in texmf with that term.

Comment: Package normally don't use `\includegraphics`. It is *provided* by the `graphicx` package. I'm not sure what your issue is, but if the size is wrong see [Image from \includegraphics showing in wrong image size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/image-from-includegraphics-showing-in-wrong-image-size).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Either of the packages `graphics` or `graphicx` will allow you to use `\includegraphics`

Comment: Yeah, but there is no reason to (only) load the old `graphics` any longer. `graphicx` loads it already and provide the modern interface which allows for options.

Comment: As you wrote: they allow you to use `\includegraphics` but the question is which packages are _using_ it...

Comment: @BernS it's not clear from the question exactly what is meant. `graphicx` is in the MWE, so it's not a question about what package is loading `graphicx`. So what does the OP want?

Comment: @Martin but if the question is about what package provide the command, then it's worth mentioning the older `graphics` package.

Comment: I think @User6830 should definitely clarify what he wants, as in the current form this won't help anyone else searching for answers.