# Why does scaling a figure eliminate part of it?

Tags: graphics, pdf

I have a bunch of graphics produced by SAS software. When I put them in my document using e.g.

```
      \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[scale = 1]{FitPlot}
         \caption{Parameters by quantile}
       \label{G:fitplot1}
  \end{figure}
```

they are fine and there is a line around the entire figure. But when I scale them, e.g.,

```
      \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.75]{FitPlot}
         \caption{Parameters by quantile}
       \label{G:fitplot1}
  \end{figure}
```

there is a line around only three sides (top, left and right).

I tried different scales and I tried adding vspace but nothing helped.

The same thing happens with many different figures.

I'd like to be able to scale my figures and keep the box.

EDIT: I also asked this on Quora. That has the figure and it is [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-LaTeX-change-my-graphic-when-I-scale-it-see-details):

Comment: Rounding errors, perhaps. Can you make the image available for experimenting?

Comment: This may depend on the zoom level of your viewer as well.

Comment: @egreg How should I make the image available?

Comment: May be is a problem of the metadata of the image. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10399/11604

Comment: @PeterFlom I downloaded the image from Quora, but have no problem when scaling it at 75%.

Comment: @egreg That is very odd. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @PeterFlom Is the image I downloaded exactly the same as yours? Sometimes in the uploading process something can be modified.

Comment: @egreg looks identical to me.

Comment: @PeterFlom [Click here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdlFn.png) for seeing what I get with `scale=0.75`. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using WinEdt on Windows 7 and Tex Live (which I got from TUG).

Comment: @werner Zooming in fixed it. How strange!  Thanks. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @PeterFlom: Zooming would not affect the printing, only the visual on your screen in the viewer. Right?

Comment: Printing is now working OK.  Thanks @Werner.  I could swear it didn't work once.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a viewer artifact at certain zoom levels, not a (La)TeX issue.