# Inserting PNG file as is

Tags: graphics, scaling, png

I'm inserting a PNG file and it's rendered enlarged, somehow.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
hello, world.
the following screenshot should be rendered in 1:1 scale, isn't it?

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{screenshot.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot I desire to insert: http://conus.info/tmp/screenshot.png
I use XeLaTeX.

And here is a result: http://conus.info/tmp/result.pdf

All I want is to insert a PNG picture (screenshot), so it will be rendered in the same width/height in PDF viewed at 100%.

The size of `screenshot.png` is 726 pixels by 489 pixels.
I want it to be exacly the same size when viewed in Acrobat Reader at 100%.

What should I do?

What are the best practices of inserting screenshots into TeX and exporting them to PDF?

Comment: 1 px is not equal to 1 mm on the PDF page... what do you mean exactly the same size ?

Comment: What to do to make it equal? How to insert screenshots to TeX and export to PDF?

Comment: you can use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{screenshot}` to fit in the text

Comment: I tried, than it's smaller.

Comment: I mean that's how you adjust the width. What is the image final size in dimensions of length pt,cm, mm etc. ?

Comment: basically you can't. You have no way of knowing what the resolution of the screen is so you may make it work for your current screen but opening it on a different computer with a different screen will be wrong.

Comment: I've found that scaling image to 0.75 is close to what I need. Just interesting, where this value is came from?

Comment: I downloaded you image, and tried it. I see it typeset at the exact same size as what you have created the screenshot at, namely `265x172mm`. The ppt-setting for the image is `72`, maybe that is not what you intended, might be an artifact from whatever screenshot-program you used, or imaging-software, if used on the file.

Comment: Here are similar questions: [one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/image-from-includegraphics-showing-in-wrong-image-size) and [two](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10397/how-to-include-picture-in-original-size-into-document-page-on-center/10399#10399)

Comment: My scaling value is 0.65 (not 0.75 as yours!) Also I am quite not sure that the Acrobat's idea of "100%" is actual 100%. Did you measure the page on your screen with regular ruler? Are you sure that on different screen it will be the same?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This question cannot have general answer for ALL monitors.

The size of the PNG image on the screen depends on the screen resolution (e.g. 110.27 PPI (pixels per inch) for my MacBook), and on Retina (220 PPI) it will be twice smaller.

And the size of image inside PDF, shown at real 100%, will be monitor-independent.

Thus solution for my monitor:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{screenshot.png}
```

will be different from yours:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{screenshot.png}
```

Comment: don't forget the \usepackage{graphicx}  AND... the path will most certainly not be screenshot.png more like  /Users/mhearn/Documents/original.png

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height = 0.3, width = 0.6]{crocodile.png}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiling your document example trow  the error: `Unknown float option`. In preamble you need to load the `float` package.